# How does event handler of Bloomberg API library behave?

Tags: java, bloomberg

https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/java/3.18/com/bloomberglp/blpapi/Session.html

This page says `A Session is asynchronous if an EventHandler object is supplied when it is constructed.` Does that mean the order of the events received by `EventHandler` is not guaranteed even the `SubscriptionList` contains 1 ticker only?

Answer (score 0):

This is not about event order but about how you retrieve the event - in synchronous mode, you need to call nextEvent to get the next event - in asynchronous mode the `processEvent` method of your event handler will be called each time a new event is published.

Comment: I printed the thread ID inside `processEvent` and I found that the ID are not the same. I don't know if I need to add some concurrency control when I handle the event to preserve the order.

Comment: I see what you mean - yes you need to handle the concurrency properly (i.e. ensure correct publication of the data to a different thread). I hadn't really thought about whether the order is preserved in that context...